# Open a session file and show the last document lines at the top of the window

Tags: notepad++

Session file entry for one of the files to be opened by Notepad++ 7.4.2:

```
<File firstVisibleLine="36070" xOffset="0" scrollWidth="1232" startPos="1677659" endPos="1677659" selMode="0" lang="Normal Text" encoding="-1" filename="<pathToFile>" backupFilePath="" originalFileLastModifTimestamp="1547671177" mapFirstVisibleDisplayLine="39239" mapFirstVisibleDocLine="36070" mapLastVisibleDocLine="36102" mapNbLine="56" mapHigherPos="1677659" mapWidth="326" mapHeight="224" mapKByteInDoc="1639" mapWrapIndentMode="1" mapIsWrap="yes" />
```

**(1)** After the file (length changes daily) has been loaded, I want to see the 16 last lines of the document at the top of the window.

If impossible: **(2)** How can I see always the last x lines of the document? (x = number of lines of the window)

Option "Settings | Preferences | Editing | Enable scrolling beyond last line" is checked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to scroll beyond the end automatically for option (1), but for option (2):  If you have [PythonScript](https://github.com/bruderstein/PythonScript/), you can use `editor.documentEnd()` to scroll to the end of the active document.  To automatically scroll to end on open, run the following script:

```py
# encoding=utf-8
"""in response to https://superuser.com/questions/1395356/open-a-session-file-and-show-the-last-document-lines-at-the-top-of-the-window"""
from Npp import *

def su1395356_ScrollToEnd_Callback(args):
    """this will scroll to the end of the current file"""
    b = args['bufferID']
    notepad.activateBufferID(b)
    editor.documentEnd()

def su1395356_EndCallback():
    """This deactivates (clears) the scroll-to-end callback"""
    notepad.clearCallbacks(su1395356_ScrollToEnd_Callback)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    """This registers (activates) the scroll-to-end callback"""
    su1395356_EndCallback()
    notepad.callback(su1395356_ScrollToEnd_Callback, [NOTIFICATION.FILEOPENED])
```

Every file you open after running this script should scroll to the end of the buffer when you open it.

To stop this callback, **Plugins > PythonScript > Show Console**, then run `su1395356_EndCallback()` from the immediate-line.  Or, the end-callback could be placed in a separate script, which imports this first, and then calls the `su1395356_EndCallback()` function.

If you restart NPP, the callback won't be active any more, so you'll need to run the script again.  Or, you might want to import this script from your `startup.py`, with **Plugins > Python Script > Configuration...** setting "Initialisation" to "ATSTARTUP", which will make it automatically start

If you don't have it in `startup.py`, you might want to use the **Configuration...** dialog to add it to the **Menu Items** list; once that's done and NPP is restarted, you can use **Settings > Shortcut Mapper** to assign a keyboard shortcut.

---

**edit:** Figured out for (1): edit the first function and add another function, as below.  Set `n=16` to however many lines you want it, or make it a parameter, as desired.  This is just a starting point.

```py
def su1395356_ScrollToEnd_Callback(args):
    """this will scroll to the end of the current file"""
    b = args['bufferID']
    notepad.activateBufferID(b)
    su1395356_AlternateScrollToLastNLines()

def su1395356_AlternateScrollToLastNLines():
    """will scroll the last n, assuming **Settings | Preferences | Editing | Enable scrolling beyond last line** enabled"""
    n = 16
    editor.scrollToEnd()
    for i in range(n-1):        # use n-1 because one row is already visible
        editor.lineScrollUp()
```